# stop AnimationDrawable after 3 repeats in Android

Tags: android, animation

I wondering if there is a way to stop AnimationDrawable after it repeats for X number of times (let's say 3 times) just like Animation objects.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you should use

> AnimationListener

and override the onAnimationRepeat

>

```
 public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                if (counter == 3) {
                // break 
                }  // else go on
            }
```

Comment: I would use the listener but I cannot set a listener to AnimationDrawable object as I would do to the Animation object

Comment: i would advise you to use one of the sub-classes of Animation and avoid the AnimationDrawable object

Comment: But then how can I use frame by frame animation to play a small clip that consist of many images?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811829/show-multiple-images-animation

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x==3){parentView.clearAnimation();}
```

where parentView is the view you are applying the animation to.

Comment: but then how would I know that the animation finished one loop ?

Comment: Sorry, I might be missing something.  x is whatever your loop counter is.  Assuming for(int x=0;x<loops;x++) then x==3 is the start of the 4th loop.

Comment: I believe the animation happens in another thread than the main thread so you can't actually do that to achieve looping